# Formula for copying whole row and pasting to sheet2 base on a condition

Tags: excel

I have a database for all the "active" files in the office.  I always had to copy and paste the whole row and pasting it on a different sheet when the case becomes inactive or placed in storage,.

Is there a formula where I can add the formula: If I add the word "Storage" on AJ then excel will copy the sheet1 A1 row and paste it on sheet 2 wherever it's has the next available row open.

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: sure, anything as long as it works lol

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Worksheet Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

When a cell in column AJ on `Sheet1` changes to "Storage", that entire row will be copied to the next available row on `Sheet2`.

Right click on *Sheet1* then *View Code* and enter the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("AJ")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change to your sheet name as needed
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Target.Value = "Storage" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(lastRow, 1)
        Target.Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much this really helps

Comment: Now I am thinking I will do a different sheet which indicate which Employee has which Case.  So Can I use the same formula, with multiple If Target.Value = "Employee's Name"  then Copy this to a different Sheet?

Comment: You might be able to re-purpose this code, yes. [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-select-case-statements) might be useful too.

Comment: Can you do one for if Column J has "Storage" copy to Storage, If Value = "Name1" copy to "Sheet2" , Name2 to Sheet3, and so on.  up to "Name7"

Comment: That should probably be a new question actually. Though I already gave you a hint with `Select Case`.